# SWT Sash/SashForm mirroring

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have tried implementing upper and lower SashForms (Children A and B) inside a horizontal SashForm (Parent). I want to be able to drag a (vertical)sash of one of the Children (child A) and have the (vertical)sash of the other child (Child B) mimic exactly the horizontal position of A.
To do this I tried a hack creating a 'ModifiedSashForm' that exposes SashForms sashes:

```
public Sash[] getSashes() {
return sashes;
```

}

I then created a class that extends ModifiedSashForm and overrides

```
public void onDragSash(Event event){
```

...

that sends a note to a listener (eg Child A) that B's sash has been dragged:
    if(sash.getParent().getData(WidgetData.DATA_DRAG_SOURCE).equals(WidgetData.DRAG_SOURCE.SOURCE)){
            fireSashDragged(event, sashIndex);
        }}

Child A then substitutes B's sash as the event source (!):

```
if(sashes[sashIndex]!=null){
            event.widget=sashes[sashIndex];
        }

        listener.onDragSash(event);
```

and I get a somewhat functioning gui. However I get problems with the sashes getting out of sync. The code is nasty and I would rather not butcher SWT in this way.
I then tried getting Child B's weights and pushing them into A - but again get problems - especially when sashes are dragged close to each other, the listeners weight order flips.

Next I tried using Sash and FormLayout. Example code is below - but I still can't get the upper vertical sash to exactly mimic the movement of the lower vertical sash and vice versa.

//Based on http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/ SWT Snippet107

```
public class SashTest {
final private List<Sash> listeners = new ArrayList<Sash>();
private Shell shell;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SashTest().run();

}

void run() {
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("SashTest");
    this.shell = shell;
    init();

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

void init() {

    final FormLayout form = new FormLayout();
    shell.setLayout(form);

    SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
    sashForm.setLayoutData(new FormData());
    Composite comp1 = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
    comp1.setLayout(new FormLayout());
    createTopArea(comp1);

    Composite comp2 = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
    comp2.setLayout(new FormLayout());
    createBottomArea(comp2);

}

void createTopArea(Composite comp) {
    Button button1 = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
    FormData fd_button1 = new FormData();
    fd_button1.bottom = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button1.right = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button1.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button1.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    button1.setLayoutData(fd_button1);
    button1.setText("Button 1");

    final Sash sash = new Sash(comp, SWT.VERTICAL);
    FormData fd_sash = new FormData();
    fd_sash.bottom = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_sash.right = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_sash.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_sash.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    sash.setLayoutData(fd_sash);
    //add the upper sash to listeners for bottom sash movement
    listeners.add(sash);

    Button button2 = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
    FormData fd_button2 = new FormData();
    fd_button2.bottom = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button2.right = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button2.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button2.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    button2.setLayoutData(fd_button2);
    button2.setText("Button 2");

    FormData button1Data = new FormData();
    button1Data.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    button1Data.right = new FormAttachment(sash, 0);
    button1Data.top = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    button1Data.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    button1.setLayoutData(button1Data);

    final int limit = 20, percent = 50;
    final FormData sashData = new FormData();
    sashData.left = new FormAttachment(percent, 0);
    sashData.top = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    sashData.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    sash.setLayoutData(sashData);
    sash.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            Rectangle sashRect = sash.getBounds();
            Rectangle shellRect = shell.getClientArea();
            int right = shellRect.width - sashRect.width - limit;
            e.x = Math.max(Math.min(e.x, right), limit);
            if (e.x != sashRect.x) {
                sashData.left = new FormAttachment(0, e.x);
                shell.layout();
                notifyListeners(sashData);
            }
        }
    });

    FormData button2Data = new FormData();
    button2Data.left = new FormAttachment(sash, 0);
    button2Data.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    button2Data.top = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    button2Data.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    button2.setLayoutData(button2Data);

}

void createBottomArea(Composite comp) {
    Button button3 = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
    FormData fd_button1 = new FormData();
    fd_button1.bottom = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button1.right = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button1.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button1.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    button3.setLayoutData(fd_button1);
    button3.setText("Button 3");

    final Sash sash2 = new Sash(comp, SWT.VERTICAL);
    FormData fd_sash2 = new FormData();
    fd_sash2.bottom = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_sash2.right = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_sash2.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_sash2.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    sash2.setLayoutData(fd_sash2);

    Button button4 = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
    FormData fd_button2 = new FormData();
    fd_button2.bottom = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button2.right = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button2.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_button2.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    button4.setLayoutData(fd_button2);
    button4.setText("Button 4");

    FormData button3Data = new FormData();
    button3Data.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    button3Data.right = new FormAttachment(sash2, 0);
    button3Data.top = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    button3Data.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    button3.setLayoutData(button3Data);

    final int limit = 20, percent = 50;
    final FormData sashData2 = new FormData();
    sashData2.left = new FormAttachment(percent, 0);
    sashData2.top = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    sashData2.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    sash2.setLayoutData(sashData2);
    sash2.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            Rectangle sashRect = sash2.getBounds();
            Rectangle shellRect = shell.getClientArea();
            int right = shellRect.width - sashRect.width - limit;
            e.x = Math.max(Math.min(e.x, right), limit);
            if (e.x != sashRect.x) {
                sashData2.left = new FormAttachment(0, e.x);
                shell.layout();
            }
        }
    });

    FormData button4Data = new FormData();
    button4Data.left = new FormAttachment(sash2, 0);
    button4Data.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    button4Data.top = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    button4Data.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    button4.setLayoutData(button4Data);

}

void notifyListeners(FormData formData){
    for(Sash sash: listeners){
        Rectangle sashRect = sash.getBounds();

        FormData sashData = formData;
        sash.setLayoutData(sashData);
        shell.layout();
    }

}
```

}

Do I have to write my own widget to do this or is it possible with Sash/SashForm?

Baz, I edited your class here (too big for comments):

```
public class SashMirror {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setMinimumSize(new Point(200, 200));
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
    final SashForm divider = new SashForm(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
    divider.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    final SashForm top = new SashForm(divider, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    top.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    final SashForm bottom = new SashForm(divider, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    bottom.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Canvas canvasTopLeft = new Canvas(top, SWT.NONE);
    canvasTopLeft
            .setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
    canvasTopLeft.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Canvas canvasTopMiddle = new Canvas(top, SWT.NONE);
    canvasTopMiddle.setBackground(SWTResourceManager
            .getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    canvasTopMiddle.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Canvas canvasTopRight = new Canvas(top, SWT.NONE);
    canvasTopRight.setBackground(SWTResourceManager
            .getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
    canvasTopRight.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Canvas canvasBottomLeft = new Canvas(bottom, SWT.NONE);
    canvasBottomLeft.setBackground(SWTResourceManager
            .getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_YELLOW));
    canvasBottomLeft.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Canvas canvasBottomMiddle = new Canvas(bottom, SWT.NONE);
    canvasBottomMiddle.setBackground(SWTResourceManager
            .getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_RED));
    canvasBottomMiddle.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Canvas canvasBottomRight = new Canvas(bottom, SWT.NONE);
    canvasBottomRight.setBackground(SWTResourceManager
            .getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));
    canvasBottomRight.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    top.setWeights(new int[] { 2, 2, 2 });
    bottom.setWeights(new int[] { 2, 2, 2 });

    canvasBottomLeft.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            top.setWeights(bottom.getWeights());
        }
    });

    canvasTopLeft.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            bottom.setWeights(top.getWeights());
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

This works flawlessly:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    final SashForm top = new SashForm(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    top.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    final SashForm bottom = new SashForm(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    bottom.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Button topLeft = new Button(top, SWT.PUSH);
    topLeft.setText("Top left");
    new Button(top, SWT.PUSH).setText("Top right");
    Button bottomLeft = new Button(bottom, SWT.PUSH);
    bottomLeft.setText("Bottom left");
    new Button(bottom, SWT.PUSH).setText("Bottom right");

    topLeft.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            bottom.setWeights(top.getWeights());
        }
    });

    bottomLeft.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            top.setWeights(bottom.getWeights());
        }
    });

    top.setWeights(new int[] {1,2});
    bottom.setWeights(new int[] {1,2});

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Before resize:

[image]

After resize:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

I noticed that the `SashForm` you actually resize eventually goes out of sync. I "fixed" this by changing the `Listener` to:

```
topLeft.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
    {
        bottom.setWeights(top.getWeights());
        // Resize the source SashForm as well to fix out of sync!
        top.setWeights(bottom.setWeights());
    }
});
```

Comment: Agreed. I have added a little complexity to mimic my application. Note I only have listeners on the left canvasses. See how sashes dissapear/don't exactly mimic the area above/below when you drag the sashes with listeners around a bit.

Comment: @DonSmythe I don't really understand your comment. You could however try getting rid of `FormData` in your code. I'm pretty sure you don't really need it. `GridData` should do.

Comment: Apologies, I couldn't paste the code in my follow up comment. I re-implemented an example class "SashMirror" and posted it at the bottom of my original post. My reply to your post refers to the SashMirror class.

Comment: @DonSmythe Yeah, you're right. It does get out of sync eventually... I'll have a look.

Comment: @DonSmythe Updated my answer. I think I found a "solution". It's a shame there is not built-in way to do this...

Comment: @DonSmythe [Here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422939) is a bug report about this.